# Duplicate image with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, image

I want to display/duplicate a thumbnail image from existing html with jquery.

**HTML**

```
<div class="iosSliderButtons hidden-print hidden-xs">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="button first selected" id="item0" 
        style="cursor: pointer; background-image: url("//media.dustin.eu/image/152748/60/50/bo-beoplay-s3-svart-2-pack.jpg"); background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("body").prepend('<div class="productImage"></div>');
$("#item0").clone().appendTo(".productImage");
//Also added all classes
$(".productImage").addClass(".button .first .selected .slider .iosSliderButtons .hidden-print .hidden-xs .iosSlider");
```

But the thumbnail won't show? Even though I can see the html being printed, and can be seen in the Chrome inspect tool?

Henrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have problem with `"` in your code.

Check this working version:
https://jsfiddle.net/maxim_mazurok/g6wka59o/2/

```js
$("body").prepend('<div class="productImage"></div>');
$("#item0").clone().attr('id', ('item' + (parseInt('item0'.substr(4)) + 1))).appendTo(".productImage");
//Also added all classes
$(".productImage").addClass(".button .first .selected .slider .iosSliderButtons .hidden-print .hidden-xs .iosSlider");
```

```html
<div class="iosSliderButtons hidden-print hidden-xs">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="button first selected" id="item0" 
        style='cursor: pointer; background-image: url("//media.dustin.eu/image/152748/60/50/bo-beoplay-s3-svart-2-pack.jpg"); background-repeat: no-repeat; width:100px; height:100px'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```